# Restful API to run ETL on a list of input values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating a controller for Model `M`

```
public class M { 
  public int Id { get; set; }; 
  public string Name { get; set; };
  ......
```

and defined the following actions.

```
// GET api/M/
public IEnumerable<M> GetAll() 
// GET api/M/1
public M Get(int Id)
```

Now I need to add an action for loading the data. The action will receive a list of `Name`s and the system will run ETL process to load all the raw data which `Name`s are on the list. (The actual data is not posted to the action, only the list of raw identifiers will be posted). It may have the following format.

```
// On database table, insert into M from raw files which names are in the list posted
void Load([FromBody]List<string> names) // Post or Put?
```

The typical post has the following signature

```
Void Load (M m)
```

How should the web-api action be defined for the loading action? Should it be Post or Put?

Comment: You should always consider that non GET and POST requests are sometimes forbidden by proxies/routers

Comment: You want to get some data ... why not use GET method for that?

Comment: @sirrufo it's not getting but loading data.

Comment: Ok, then POST it

Comment: How expensive or long-running is the ETL process? If it runs asynchronously then I would define it in terms of a "Processing" resource: Start job: `POST /etl-jobs` (returns 201 with path to job id), Get job status: `GET /etl-jobs/{jobId}`, and when the job is finished the Get job status result will have a URI to the inserted data.

Comment: I agree with Dai, the resource collection is the etl jobs itself, POST would create job

Comment: What about actions that don't fit into the world of CRUD operations? http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#restful OR http://restful-api-design.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#actions